Spherical colour surface plot in python
I'm trying to recreate a plot like this:

but with the colours on the surface of a sphere, similar to this:

So the top and bottom (Z axis) of the sphere should be blue, the front and back (X axis) should be red, and the left and right (Y axis) should be green.
My idea is to use the XYZ coordinates of points on the surface of the sphere as RGB values, e.g. if the coordinate is 1,0,0 (the tip of the back of the sphere), then the RGB value of 1,0,0 = red.
However, when I try and plot this, the surface doesn't have the the desired RGB colours but rather an unknown scalar value:

What am I doing wrong?
Here's my code that produced the above image:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

# Create a grid of theta and phi values
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

# Create the meshgrid
theta, phi = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)

# Define the radius of the sphere
r = 1

# Convert spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates
x = r * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
y = r * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
z = r * np.cos(phi)

# Combine absolute values of X, Y, and Z to get final color
color = np.stack([np.abs(x), np.abs(y), np.abs(z)], axis=1)

# Create the plotly figure
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=x, y=y, z=z, surfacecolor=color)])

# Update layout
fig.update_layout(scene=dict(aspectmode="data"))

# Show the interactive plot
fig.show()


Does this answer solve the problem? Your question isn't a complete duplicate, but it seems you're trying to get something similar. The answer shows how to use Plotly's Mesh3d to get a sphere mesh with its vertices colored by a function of (x,y,z).

Thanks! That answer didn't quite solve it (I couldn't come up with a mathematical function to turn the xyz coordinates into a meaningful intensity value), but I was able to adapt it's use of constructing the sphere from vertices to simply assign RGB values to each vertex, and it works perfectly (see my edited post)!

Thanks to Iburakov's comment, I was able to solve the problem by constructing a sphere from vertices, and then assigning an RGB value to each vertex individually:
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

N = 100  # Sphere resolution (both rings and segments, can be separated to different constants)
theta, z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, N), np.linspace(-1, 1, N))
r = np.sqrt(1 - z ** 2)
x = r * np.cos(theta)
y = r * np.sin(theta)
x = x.ravel()
y = y.ravel()
z = z.ravel()

# Triangle indices
indices = np.arange(N * (N - 1) - 1)
i1 = np.concatenate([indices, (indices // N + 1) * N + (indices + 1) % N])
i2 = np.concatenate([indices + N, indices // N * N + (indices + 1) % N])
i3 = np.concatenate([(indices // N + 1) * N + (indices + 1) % N, indices])

# Calculate individual RGB values for each vertex based on x, y, z coordinates
rgb_values = np.stack([np.abs(x), np.abs(y), np.abs(z)], axis=-1)

# Create the Plotly figure
fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Mesh3d(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        vertexcolor=rgb_values,  # Specify RGB values for each vertex
        i=i1,
        j=i2,
        k=i3
    )
])

fig.show()

Which produces my desired output:

